# Add column that keeps count of distinct values grouped by a variable in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, count

I have a pandas dataframe called `df` that looks like this

```
name   test_type   block  
joe    0           1                
joe    0           1            
joe    1           2            
joe    1           2            
joe    0           3            
joe    0           3            
jim    1           1            
jim    1           1            
jim    0           2            
jim    0           2           
jim    1           3            
jim    1           3
```

I want to add a column that keeps track of every time I get a new value of `block` for each person under `name`, but divided by `test_type`

Here is what I need:

```
name   test_type   block   block_by_test_type
joe    0           1       1         
joe    0           1       1     
joe    1           2       1     
joe    1           2       1     
joe    0           3       2     
joe    0           3       2     
jim    1           1       1     
jim    1           1       1     
jim    0           2       1     
jim    0           2       1     
jim    1           3       2     
jim    1           3       2
```

I've been using `groupby` and `cumsum`, but I can't manage to get exactly what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "*divided by `test_type`*"? you can't divide by zero, did you rather mean ***subtracted***? Also why are the jim block 2 rows have a output of 1 and not 2?

Comment: @mozway I just mean separated by, so you count separately for test_type == 0 and test_type == 1

Comment: your output doesn't match your logic, but I think a simple cumulative count is what you need here (or window function if you're coming from the SQL world)

Comment: @Umar.H could you specify why you think the output doesn't match the logic? I want to count how many times I get a new value for block, separately for each person and test_type, so I think the example is correct

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your pattern of the output is based on after one run of [0,1], your value will increase by 1 for the same person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your were close with `groupby` and `cumsum`.  `duplicated` makes it all come together.

```
df['block_by_test_type'] = (
    df.groupby(['name','test_type'], as_index=False)
        .apply(lambda x: (~x['block'].duplicated()).cumsum()).droplevel(0)
)

print(df)
```

**Result**

```
   name  test_type  block  block_by_test_type
0   joe          0      1                   1
1   joe          0      1                   1
2   joe          1      2                   1
3   joe          1      2                   1
4   joe          0      3                   2
5   joe          0      3                   2
6   jim          1      1                   1
7   jim          1      1                   1
8   jim          0      2                   1
9   jim          0      2                   1
10  jim          1      3                   2
11  jim          1      3                   2
```